# Laravel Nova: Create filter for date and time

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-nova

So Im trying to edit a filter that i have for nova resource i want that filter to filter on date and time right now its filtering only on time. Ive tried different thing so far the best option i found was here:https://nova.laravel.com/docs/customization/filters.html
The problem i have now is that whenever i try to change anything within this component that the command created nothing is reflected in the browser. Ive tried recompiling my assets and clearing the cache but nothing works. Does someone here know how to use this nova:custom-filter assets, or how to add time to a date filter if so please help!

I tied to use the custom filter but it doesnt display in the browser
ive also tried just using a custom filter component someone else made but that also didnt work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.